# Extração dos dados diferentes de duas listas de objetos

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

Estou trabalhando em uma WEB API e preciso retirar alguns valores contidos em uma lista e que estão contidos em outra. Para que ficar ilustrado melhor seria o equivalente a retirar os dados de uma lista onde o usuário em questão já tem cadastrado. 
Abaixo segue o método *Get* da *web api* que está fazendo a requisição e a forma que estou fazendo para tentar fazer essa extração porém o mesmo está apenas me retornando os valores que o usuário já tem cadastrado primeiro seguidos de todos valores da tabela depois, poderiam me dar uma luz por gentileza.

```
// GET: api/Jogos?ID_Jogador
public IEnumerable<Jogos> GetJogos(long ID_Jogador)
{
    //Desabilita a criação de proxy que gera erros na chamada
    //db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    var query =
       (
            from jO in db.Jogos
            from jJ in db.JogosJogador
            where jJ.ID_Jogador == ID_Jogador && jJ.ID_Jogo == jO.ID_Jogo
            select new
            {
                jO.ID_Jogo,
                jO.Nome_Jogo,
                jO.Nome_Icone_Jogo,
                jO.Plataforma,
                jO.Genero
            }
        );
    List<Jogos> jogosJogadorTem = new List<Jogos>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        jogosJogadorTem.Add(new Jogos
        {
            ID_Jogo = item.ID_Jogo,
            Nome_Jogo = item.Nome_Jogo,
            Nome_Icone_Jogo = item.Nome_Icone_Jogo,
            Genero = item.Genero,
            Plataforma = item.Plataforma
        });
    }
    List<Jogos> todosJogos = db.Jogos.ToList();
    var diferenca1 = jogosJogadorTem.Except(todosJogos);
    var diferenca2 = todosJogos.Except(jogosJogadorTem);
    var juncao = diferenca2.Union(diferenca1).ToList();
    return juncao.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor? não consegui entender o que você quer fazer lendo a descrição e o código.

Comment: Você quer mostrar todos os jogos que o usuário não tem?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção porém o comentário abaixo já atendeu minha necessidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar Except é necessário implementar IEqualityComparer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Mas você também pode fazer assim:

```
// retorna os jogos não contidos no "jogosJogadorTem"
todosJogos.Where(x => !jogosJogadorTem.Any(y => y.ID_Jogo == x.ID_Jogo)).ToList();
```

Comment: Deu certinho, muitissimo obrigado de verdade